# can I add <script type="text/ng-template" inside angular template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating a directive in angularjs. I need to add 
[nsPopover](https://github.com/nohros/nsPopover)
 in it. But nsPopover need the popover content as a template inside `<script type="text/ng-template"` tag. Can I add `<script type="text/ng-template"` inside my directive template, like

```
template: ['<div class="myClass">',
'<script type="text/ng-template" id="price_actionPopup">',
'<div class="triangle"></div>',
'</script>',
```

When I added, it is just printing `<div class="triangle"></div>` in the page. Do I need to add something elase?

Comment: Don't you just reference the template using the id? (price_actionPopup)

Comment: yes you can. you can also put your template directly to $templateCache

Comment: I have edited question. Yes I tried and the contents of `<script>` tag is just printed on page

Comment: Could you provide more complete code for reference?